# Rosetta Stone for Linux Distributions?

Tags: linux, distributions

Is there is something like a [Rosetta Stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_Stone) for the different Linux Distributions?

Perhaps a site where you can look up a commands, configuration files or problem solutions for a specific task organized as translations of ones of another distribution (you know well).

For example you know Debian based distributions well and you want to know the Fedora equivalent to

```
dpkg -S /bin/bar
```

or

```
dpkg --get-selections > foo
dpkg --set-selections < foo
```

or

```
apt-cache search foobar --names-only
```

etc.

There is [a Rosetta Stone for different Unices](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html), but it is not that detailed and does not really differentiates between different Distributions.

Comment: Probably not since there would be an infinite number of different versions and such.

Comment: @well, I would be fine if a site would just mention the most popular distros/most usual tasks ...

Comment: All these details are stored in a magic proprietary format in a giant database that powers my AdmnistrateAnythingBot© that will soon make human system administrators obsolete.

Answer (score 5):

I think the service is called http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: no idea who downvoted this. ( glaring eyes at everyone ) +1

Comment: Why www though?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what OP asks for is a chrestomathy of package managers.
You can find one on the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Rosetta), which compares its package manager Pacman with other package managers from different distributions and several command-line flags.

Answer (score 0):

http://distrowatch.com/ will, at least, tell you what software is available in what distro...